# apply jquery function to JSON array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i wrote a simple function to apply math through JSON array values and it works with no problem .

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var arr1 = {"gold":"1000","iron":"2000","wood":"4500","food":"800"} ;
    var arr2 = [{"gold":"100","iron":"80","wood":"120","food":"70"}];
    Array.max = function( array ){
    return Math.max.apply( Math, array );
    };
    Array.min = function( array ){
        return Math.min.apply( Math, array );
    };
    function getValidenum(resources,cost) {
        var output = [] ;
         $.each(cost, function(i, item) {
          output.push(Math.floor(resources.gold / item.gold)) ;  
          output.push(Math.floor(resources.iron / item.iron)) ;
          output.push(Math.floor(resources.wood / item.wood)) ;
          output.push(Math.floor(resources.food / item.food)) ;
        });
        return Array.min(output) ;
    }
    alert(getValidenum(arr1,arr2));
});
```

the issues appear when i add more values to the second array and tried to to loop through the array to apply the function .

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var arr1 = {"gold":"1000","iron":"2000","wood":"4500","food":"800"} ;
    var arr2 = [{"gold":"100","iron":"80","wood":"120","food":"70"},{"gold":"10","iron":"20","wood":"50","food":"30"}];
    Array.max = function( array ){
    return Math.max.apply( Math, array );
    };
    Array.min = function( array ){
        return Math.min.apply( Math, array );
    };
    function getValidenum(resources,cost) {
        var output = [] ;
         $.each(cost, function(i, item) {
          output.push(Math.floor(resources.gold / item.gold)) ;  
          output.push(Math.floor(resources.iron / item.iron)) ;
          output.push(Math.floor(resources.wood / item.wood)) ;
          output.push(Math.floor(resources.food / item.food)) ;
        });
        return Array.min(output) ;
    }
     $.each(arr2, function(i, item) {
          alert(getValidenum(arr1,item));
        });

});
```

instead of showing the result for 2 times for the 2 arrays in arr2

```
var arr2 = [{"gold":"100","iron":"80","wood":"120","food":"70"},{"gold":"10","iron":"20","wood":"50","food":"30"}];
```

it shows NaN twice

Comment: You should try to use `parseInt` you're trying to operate on strings

Answer (score 0):

You've changed what you're using as the second argument to `getValidenum` between your two examples.

In the first you pass in `arr2`, an array of objects.

In the second, you pass in the `item` parameter of your anonymous function, an object from the `arr2` array.

If you altered your first example to also utilize a `$.each` in calling `getValidenum` you would see a similar failure.

The `NaN` itself results when the `cost` parameter of `getValidenum` is an object because the `.each` splits the object attributes into key (`i`) and value (`item`).  So in an iteration during your second example you'd have values like:

```
i === "gold"
item === "100"
```

When you then attempt to access `item.gold` you're actually asking for `"100".gold` which is `undefined` and yields `NaN` when you divide by it.